# SQL : To get one of the duplicates by using a case statement

Tags: sql, duplicates, case, charindex

I have a table in which there are two columns with duplicates.

```
id name  classname description 
-----------------------------
1  a     aa        aa:abcd  
2  a     Unknown   Unknown 
3  b     bb        unknown 
4  c     cc        abcd
```

Now I have a select query where in I have to filter out all the duplicates and my description is shown as identifier, my result should be like this,

```
id name identifier
-----------------
1  a   aa
2  b   NULL 
3  c   NULL
```

where all the description having either without ':' as its char index should display as NULL or Unknown as Null.

I'm using the below select query to filter the duplicates in the 'name' column , but I'm unable to use the same query for description as I'm using case for obtaining result in order to trim my description 'aa: abcd' to aa

```
    select distinct 
           id,
           (select top 1 name 
             from table1 t 
            where t.name = t1.name 
            order by case t1.classname 
                        when 'Unknown Tag Class' then 0 
                        else 1 
                     end
            ) name,
            (case when charindex(':',Description)> 0
               then substring(Description,1,(charindex(':',Description)-1)) 
            end
            ) as Identifier
    from table1  t1

In the above query I want to modify the case statement of description so that i can filter duplicates and also trim the values like "aa:abcd" to "aa" and put them in identifier column.

Need help on this.


this is the query i am using 

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects     WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[EXEC_REP_TransposedTagAttributes]')
AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
   select distinct 
      [Att : 42674] as TagID
       ,Tagname
       ,isnull([Att : 14591],'-') as OriginatingContractor
       ,isnull([Att : 14594],'-') as System
      ,(case when charindex(':',TargetName)> 0 then 
    substring(TargetName,(charindex(':',TargetName)+1),len(TargetName)) 
   end) as SystemDescription
,(case when charindex(':',TagClassDescription)> 0 then 
    substring(TagClassDescription,1,(charindex(':',TagClassDescription)-1)) 
   end) as TagIdentifier
from EXEC_REP_TransposedTagAttributes t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SourceName, TargetName FROM EXEC_REP_Associations WHERE AssociationType = '3' and TargetClassName = 'SUB SYSTEM') b ON TagName = b.SourceName
where tagname='ZIH-210053' Order by [Att : 42674]
END
ELSE
 select 'Reporting Database is being refreshed, please wait.' as errMsg
```

and the result i am geting is

### TagID   Tagname OriginatingContractor   System  SystemDescription   TagIdentifier

2609005 ZIH-210053  Hyundai Heavy Industries (Topsides) 210  Slugcatcher    NULL
2609005 ZIH-210053  Hyundai Heavy Industries (Topsides) 210  Slugcatcher    ZIH

there are also rows which have tag identifier as null and donot have duplicates

Comment: SQL Server? Or a different database system? Please add an appropriate tag. Also, are you just considering duplicates across `name` or does the eventual `identifier` also participate in the definition; i.e. is it possible that there's a row with `name` = `a` and `description` = `df:ghi`, and if so, is the result a single row with `name` `a` (how do we decide on an identifier?) or are there two rows?

Comment: It's not clear which row of duplicates have to be selected.

Comment: it isin SQL database, i want my result to have one of the duplicates, and the corressponding identifier alias with one of duplicates if duplicates exists , it should not have name = a and identifier= a:fjsa   instead it should have name=q and identifier= a (if description is a:fjsa) name=q and identifier = null (if description is afdafd or Unknown i.e., without ":" ) and also should filter all the duplicates

Comment: -Valex i want to select name and trim description by removing the part after : and display description as identifier without duplicates

Comment: this is the query i amusing where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id,name,
       CASE WHEN charindex(':',description)>0
         THEN LEFT(description,charindex(':',description)-1) 
         ELSE NULL
       END as identifier

from t as t1
where description like '%:%'
      or NOT EXISTS (select * from t where t.id<>t1.id and t.name=t1.name);
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d45df/5)